# PDO General error (HY000) when nextRowSet a statement CALLing procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a stored routine in MySQL that does a `SELECT` <del>and calls another `assert` subroutine</del> (the same issue occurs even without calling the `assert` and even with a `SELECT null;` instead of the following one):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `account_login`(IN `email` VARCHAR(50), IN `password` VARCHAR(200))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id AS id
        FROM account AS a
        WHERE a.email = email AND password_hash(password, a.password_salt) = a.password_hash
    ;

    CALL assert((SELECT FOUND_ROWS()) = 1, 'WrongLoginCredentials', 'Bad login or bad password');

END$$
```

Where `assert` calls another `throw` routine if assertion is `FALSE`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `assert`(
        IN `assertion` BOOLEAN,
        IN exceptionClass TINYTEXT,
        IN errorMessage TEXT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    IF NOT(`assertion`) THEN
        CALL throw(exceptionClass, errorMessage);
    END IF;

END$$
```

`throw` then calls a `SIGNAL 45000` if assertion failed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `throw`(
        IN exceptionClass TINYTEXT,
        IN errorMessage TEXT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    ROLLBACK;
    SELECT 1 AS exception, errorMessage as message, 42 AS code, exceptionClass as class;

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT=errorMessage,
        MYSQL_ERRNO=42,
        CLASS_ORIGIN=exceptionClass;

END$$
```

If I call this procedure in HeidiSQL using fake credentials, the signal occurs. If I call it in HeidiSQL using correct credentials, it returns the result set (`SELECT` in that `account_login` procedure).

But when I call it in PHP using PDO prepared statement:

```
        $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dbDsn, '...', '...', array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        ));

        $loginRequest = $this->pdo->prepare('CALL account_login(?, ?)');
        $loginRequest->execute(array($email, $password));

        $loginRequest->debugDumpParams();
        do {
            $resultSets[] = $loginRequest->fetchAll();
        } while ($loginRequest->nextRowset());

        $loginRequest->closeCursor();
```

Then I get an expected exception for wrong credentials (because of `SIGNAL`, fine) and an unexpected `GENERAL ERROR` for correct credentials raised by the 2nd call to `fetchAll`.

The same issue occurs no matter what's in `throw` (no `SELECT` or no `SIGNAL` or nothing at all results in the same PDO `GENERAL ERROR` when calling `account_login` with correct credentials).

The same occurs with a non prepared statement `$this->pdo->query('CALL account_login($..., $...);`

This occurs in PHP 5.3 through Apache but also occurs in PHP 5.6 through CLI too.

What's wrong in there?

Comment: I managed to get it work with a `do { ... } while ($loginRequest->nextRowset() && $loginRequest->columnCount())` but I don't get why `nextRowSet` returns ` true` once too often, forcing a `columnCount` check